# How to do Case insensitive selection in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I wanted to select all  tags which points to an swf in jQuery. I wrote the following code and which works fine

```
$(a[href$=".swf"]).each( function(){
   alert('hello');
});
```

Now if i want to include SWF also for search, what is the best way?

Comment: [See this please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619621/how-do-i-use-jquery-to-ignore-case-when-selecting)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may take a look at the [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#fn) function.

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    return (/\.swf$/i).test($(this).attr('href'));
}).each(function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```

Comment: +1, + maybe escape the dot. return (/\.swf$/i).test($(this).attr('href'));

Comment: Hey it worked.. cool...

I Made it something like this

$('a').filter(function() {
  var regexpr  = /\.SWF$|\.PDF/i;
  if((regexpr).test($(this).attr('href')))
  {
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
  }
});

Answer (score 1):

For such a basic case, why not just do something like:

```
$('a[href$=".swf"], a[href$=".SWF"]').each( function(){
   alert('hello');
});
```

In general though, Darin has pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in .swf and .SWF, you can use this:

```
$('a[href$=".swf"], a[href$=".SWF"]').each( function(){
   alert('hello');
});
```