# Case-insensitive switch-case

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement, case-sensitive

OK, so let's say I have this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#good_evening').keyup(function () {
    switch($(this).val()) {
    case 'Test':
      // DO STUFF HERE
      break;
    }
  });
});
```

... this would **only** run if you typed "Test" and *not* "test" or "TEST". How do I make it case-insensitive for JavaScript functions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use jQuery to ignore case when selecting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619621/how-do-i-use-jquery-to-ignore-case-when-selecting)

Comment: @Lazarus: This is asking about case-sensitivity for switch-case, not jQuery selectors (as the other question is).  It isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
switch($(this).val().toLowerCase()) {
    case 'test':
    // DO STUFF HERE          
    break;
}
```

Comment: Ah yes -- brilliant yet simple solution. Thanks.

Comment: 2mins faster than me. *slaps self* for editing tags before answering the question :)

Comment: @dan: glad to have helped :) @Marko: can't count the amount of times I've deleted an answer and up voted someone else ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Convert it to upper case. I believe this is how it is done, correct me if I am wrong... (dont -1 me =D )

```
$(function() {
    $('#good_evening').keyup(function () {
            switch($(this).val().toUpperCase()) {
            case 'TEST':
            // DO STUFF HERE
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Correct! But Matt was first. Sorry. :P

Answer (score 4):

Why not lowercase the value, and check against lowercase inside your switch statement?

```
$(function() {
    $('#good_evening').keyup(function () {
        switch($(this).val().toLowerCase()) {
        case 'test':
        // DO STUFF HERE
        break;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure val() is a String if it could be null
switch(String($(this).val()).toLowerCase()) {