# How do I do case-insensitive comparisons in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple `switch` function:

```
var game = prompt("What game do you want to play?");

switch(game) {
    case 'League of Legends':
        console.log("You just played that!");
    //more case statements snipped... //
    break;
}
```

If the user puts `league of legends`, not `League of Legends` would it catch that or would it reset to the default answer at the bottom of all my cases? Furthermore, how would I change it so both answers, capitalized and not, worked?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a case-insensitive comparison in JavaScript. Have you looked that up at all? Maybe `.toLowerCase()` everything as a first cut?

Comment: Make it all lower case with game.toLowerCase()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Case-insensitive switch-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690186/case-insensitive-switch-case)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Switch on a lower-cased version of the game:

```
switch (game.toLowerCase()) {
  case 'league of legends':
    console.log("You just played that!");
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Almost everyone here knew exactly what I was talking about. I researched it but probably phrased it badly because I couldn't find exactly what I wanted. But this is exactly it thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *String.toLowerCase()* or *String.toLocaleLowerCase()*

```
game.toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

String compare is case-sensitive, therefore you should either upper-case everything using `yourString.toUpperCase()` or lowercase with `yourString.toLowerCase()` if your code needs to be case-insensitive.

Answer (score -1):

[String.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

In javascript the character 'L' doesn't equal the character 'l'. Therefore 'League of Legends' wouldn't match 'league of legends'. By converting the users input to all lowercase and then matching it to a lowercase string in your switch statement, you can guarantee your program won't discriminate based on case.

Your code with `toLowerCase()`

```
var game = prompt("What game do you want to play?");
game = game.toLowerCase();

switch(game) {
    case 'league of legends':
        console.log("You just played that!");
    //more case statements snipped... //
    break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The string 'league of legends' and 'League of Legends' are different so that would fall to the default at the bottom of all your cases.

To make it work, you may use

```
switch(game.toUpperCase()) {
    case 'LEAGUE OF LEGENDS':
        console.log("You just played that!");
    //more case statements snipped... //
    break;
}
```