# Lowercase and Uppercase with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I transpose a string to lowercase using jQuery? I've tried

```
var jIsHasKids = $('#chkIsHasKids').attr('checked').toLowerCase();
```

but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does not work? What do you get? What do you want? jQuery does not provide string manipulation functions, so you can't do this with jQuery (but the language itself does).

Comment: What doesn't work? It doesn't become lower case or there is an error?

Answer (score 472, accepted):

I think you want to lowercase the checked value? Try:

```
var jIsHasKids = $('#chkIsHasKids:checked').val().toLowerCase();
```

or you want to check it, then get its value as lowercase:

```
var jIsHasKids = $('#chkIsHasKids').attr("checked", true).val().toLowerCase();
```

Comment: for input text work like this:

    `let toLowercase = function () {
        jQuery('.tolowercase').on('keypress keydown blur',function () {
            let currentVal = jQuery(this).val();
            jQuery(this).val(currentVal.toLowerCase());
       });
    };`

Answer (score 26):

If it's just for display purposes, you can render the text as upper or lower case in pure CSS, without any Javascript using the `text-transform` property:

```
.myclass {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-transform for more info.

However, note that this doesn't actually change the value to lower case; it just displays it that way. This means that if you examine the contents of the element (ie using Javascript), it will still be in its original format.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
var jIsHasKids = $('#chkIsHasKids').attr('checked');
jIsHasKids = jIsHasKids.toString().toLowerCase();
//OR
jIsHasKids = jIsHasKids.val().toLowerCase();
```

Possible duplicate with:
[How do I use jQuery to ignore case when selecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619621/how-do-i-use-jquery-to-ignore-case-when-selecting)

Answer (score 1):

$.validator.addMethod("R",function(value,element){

```
var $firstnames= (value.toLowerCase());
 var $search= ("SHIVA" || "KARTHIK" ==$firstnames  ? false :true ) ;
 return $search ;
```

}, "This user is blocked");

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked in 2011. I am answering it in September, 2021. Even though I am late by 10 years I am answering for future searchers. Good answers are already given. I will just add an alternate with jQuery's `.css` property.

```
$('#chkIsHasKids').attr("checked").val().css("text-transform","lowercase");
```

This will first check if the id `#chkIsHasKids` is checked, then will take it's value and then transform it to lower case using the CSS property. That's it!