# Jquery Search - Case insensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I have had some help on a Jquery script which creates a searchable, toggleable FAQ. The code can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/pT6dB/62/

The trouble is, if there is the word “How” with an upper case “H” and I search “h”, it wont find it. How can I make this script case insensitive?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619102/lowercase-and-uppercase-with-jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update

Alternatively, you could reduce the amount of code significantly using regular expression. [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GeekyEggo/pT6dB/72/)

```
$('#search').keyup(function(e) {
    // create the regular expression
    var regEx = new RegExp($.map($(this).val().trim().split(' '), function(v) {
            return '(?=.*?' + v + ')';
        }).join(''), 'i');

    // select all list items, hide and filter by the regex then show
    $('#result li').hide().filter(function() {
        return regEx.exec($(this).text());
    }).show();
});​
```

### Original

Based on your current algorithm for determining relative elements, you could use the jQuery `filter` method to filter your results based on the `keywords` array. Here's a rough idea:

```
// select the keywords as an array of lower case strings
var keywords = $(this).val().trim().toLowerCase().split(' ');

// select all list items, hide and filter then show
$('#result li').hide().filter(function() {
    // get the lower case text for the list element
    var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();        

    // determine if any keyword matches, return true on first success
    for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
        if (text.indexOf(keywords[i]) >= 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}).show();
```

Comment: That is really interesting, but you're demo doesn't seem to work in the same way

Comment: the problem is if someone types "is" it returns all the results. Its better I think if someone searches "oh hello" to search for results which only contain "oh" AND "hello", instead of "oh" OR "hello"

Comment: My apologises @JamesWillson, this should now work as an 'AND' rather than an 'OR'.

Comment: I came here to vote on this again, that you @Richard

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
$('#result LI:not(:contains('+keywords[i]+'))').hide();
```

to

```
$('#result LI').each(function()
{
    if(this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(keywords[i].toLowerCase()) === -1)
    {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// split the search into words
var keywords = s.toLowerCase().split(' ');

// loop over the keywords and if it's not in a LI, hide it
for(var i=0; i<keywords.length; i++) {
    $('#result LI').each(function (index, element) {
        if ($(element).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(keywords) != -1) {
            $(element).show();
        } else {
            $(element).hide();
        }
    });
}
```