# Submit form using javascript and receive it from other page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I'm trying to submit a form to a PHP page, but the data is not accessible from this page, This is my code:

**Html code:**

```
<form method="post" id="formid" action="test.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="going" id="going" value="" /> 
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#ongoing").change(function() {
    var ongoing = $(this).attr('checked');
    var input = document.getElementById('going');
    var form = document.getElementById('formid');

    if (ongoing)
        input.value = "1";
    else
        input.value = "0";

    form.submit();
});
```

**test.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['going']))
      echo $_POST['going'];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please clarify yor question, it it not clear what your problem is. Does the form submit?  what errors are you getting?

Comment: Where is your #ongoing element in the code? Do you mind adding that snippet?

Comment: <div style="margin-left:5px;">
                    <label for="ongoing"> On going Alerts </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="ongoing" id="ongoing" style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle" <?php if ($_POST['going'] == "1") echo "checked"; ?>>
                </div>
this is the #ongoing element.. and I don't get any errors, but the page submited successfully to the page test.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this! It does what you want with much less code. You were having issues because the `checked` attribute returns a `string` **not** a `boolean` value.

```
$("#ongoing").change(function() {
    var form = document.getElementById('formid');
    form.going.value = $(this).attr('checked').toLowerCase() == "checked" ? "1" : "0";
    form.submit();
});
```

The longer way looks like:

```
$("#ongoing").change(function() {
    var form = document.getElementById('formid');
    var input = document.getElementById('going');
    var isChecked = $(this).attr('checked').toLowerCase() == "true";
    if(isChecked)
        input.value = "1";
    else
        input.value = "0";
    form.submit();
});
```

Additionally! It is good practice when writing html attributes to *always* type `checked="true"` (or `"false"`) even though just `checked` is synonymous with the previous. Unpaired markup attribute-values could be mistaken by amateur coders as tag names.

See here for more [Checkboxes in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619102/lowercase-and-uppercase-with-jquery/)

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
   $("#ongoing").change(function() {
        var input = document.getElementById('going');
        var form = document.getElementById('formid');

       if($(this).is(':checked'))
       {
          input.value = "1";
       }
       else
       {
          input.value = "0";
       }

        form.submit();
    });
```