# Searching throught data-value on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I while I type I need to show elements with certain text that is equals data-value="certain text". I've tried several ways, but nothing seems to work.
Here is what I have so far.

```
$(".search").keyup(function () {

    var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
    $(".element-holder .element").each(function () {

        var current = $('.element').attr('data-name');
        if ($(".element[data-name='" + current + "']").text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
            count++;
        }
    });

});
```

This is what I need help with ;l

@Edit

HTml here

```
            <div class="element-holder ">
                        <div class="element" data-name='Adam' id='1'>
                        </div>
                        <div class="element" data-name='Eva' id='32'>
                        </div>
                        <div class="element" data-name='Sara' id='412'>
                        </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: can you display you HTML too

Comment: @YoYo There you go, added html

Comment: If you know how to use `$(this)`, use it properly....

Comment: There is no `"data-value"` attribute in `HTML`

Comment: @Rayon It is data-name, I just forgot to change it for better example, sorry @_ @. Fixed.

Comment: I don't really want to be _rude_ but what id `'somedatahere'` and `'someid'` ? ID must be unique... If you are expecting someone to put efforts for answer, you must express your efforts in your question.....

Comment: @Rayon Forgive me, I thought it was obvious enough that there is some random data out there. Fixed again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try below

```js
$(".search").keyup(function () {

        var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
        $(".element-holder .element").each(function () {

            var current = $('.element').attr('data-name');
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).fadeOut();
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                count++;
            }
        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="search"/>
 <div class="element-holder ">
<div class="element" data-name='Adam' id='1'>How to Format
</div>
<div class="element" data-name='Eva' id='32'>How to Edit
</div>
<div class="element" data-name='Sara' id='412'>Searching throught data-value on keyup
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lot of mistakes in your html .

spelling mistakes of element class used.

You did not show the search input html.

Different data attribute name.

If you are using each and make use of `$(this)` to select current element

Checkout my below demo

```
$(".search").keyup(function () {

    var entered = $(this).val();

    $(".elemnet").each(function () {
       var text = $(this).html();

       if(entered !="")
       {
          if(text.indexOf(entered) > -1)
          {

            $(this).show();
          }else
          {

             $(this).hide();
          }
        }else{

          $(".elemnet").hide();
        }
    });

});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vj7n0m3h/)**

**[Demo using data attribute](https://jsfiddle.net/vj7n0m3h/1/)**

Comment: Well, yeah. I agree, I was kinda of in hurry changing names of data-name and classes and then in the end it made no sense at all q_ q. Also data-name is suppose to have different values. I also checked your demo, but nothing seems to works on keyup @_ @. I added jquery to external resources tho.

Comment: @Harugawa : did you really check my demo ? type a or b or c . See my data attribute value its  aaaa , bbbb , ccccc . So type any of these a, b or c

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I have typed down.

Comment: Seems, to work in my own code, but not on the website, weird. Do you know only how to make so it would ignore if I either write it A or a?

Comment: yes you can use `toLowerCase();` to both data attribute value and entered value, it will change to lowercase and then you can filter . More info on it see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619621/how-do-i-use-jquery-to-ignore-case-when-selecting

Answer (score 0):

1. Searching through the entire DOM on each `keyup` is going to cause a huge performance drop. **Cache your results**
2. Throttle your `keyup` event to only fire the filter when the user pauses typing
3. Re use your regular expression instead of re creating it multiple times inside your loop

```

```
// Cache your elements before hand
var namedElements = $(".element-holder .element");

// inside your throttled keyup event handler
// Check for empty strings
var filter = (this.value || "").trim(),
    regex = new RegExp(filter, 'i');

var toShow = namedElements.filter(function(index, element) {
    var dataName = element.data("name");
    return regex.test(dataName);
});
toShow.show();

var toHide = namedElements.filter(function(index, element) {
    var dataName = element.data("name");
    return !regex.test(dataName);
});
toHide.hide();
```

```